# Using Parse.com, how can I query for objects containing a time delta (active within last 3 minutes)?

Tags: ios, date, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to build a Parse query that will retrieve the latest active users within the last 3 minutes.  Either using PFCloud or just a simple Parse query, how can I achieve this?

iOS examples preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
// Set a date variable equal to 3 minutes ago
var date = NSDate()
var threeMinutesAgo = date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-180)
// I'm using the updatedAt column in a User class
let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
query.whereKey("updatedAt", greaterThanOrEqualTo: threeMinutesAgo)    
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil && objects.count > 0 {
        // Do something with queried objects ... 
    } else {
        // Some error handling ...
    }
}
```

Mind you this only works if an "active user" per your definition is a user that has interacted with a Parse database or through a relation in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have a dummy field that you update every time the user is active. Unfortunately, you can't put this field on your `Installation` or `User` object associated with the user, because those are protected - unless you use a PFCloud call to handle it. However, cloud code calls are expensive, and if you are going to be running this call a lot, I recommend using a second, non-protected Object class that you can query against normally.

1. Create an object class, OnlineInfo, with two fields. One field is a pointer to the User object, the other is a 'lastOnline' field with a Date in it.

Store the ping like so:

```
- (void)updateLastOnline
{
  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"OnlineInfo"];
  //Store the objectID for the associated OnlineInfo object as a pointer field "onlineInfo" on the User object
  [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey"onlineInfo"] block:^(PFObject *onlineInfo, NSError *error) {
    // Do something with the returned PFObject in the gameScore variable.
    [onlineInfo setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastOnline"];
    [onlineInfo saveInBackground];
  }];
}
```

Then you can query against this 'safe' object using a standard PFQuery with two dates, which you can find on my post here:
[PFQuery by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973914/pfquery-by-date)

NOTE: You may also want to make sure this is only called every x number of minutes, to prevent spamming this against your Parse installation. You get 30 requests/second for free, so you probably don't want to send this more than once every minute, or every 5 minutes.