# Parse.com How to use whereKey:equalTo with NSDate

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsdate

I have a Parse column with Date type. I need all the objects of a specific date. When I try the following code, it is returning empty array.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:CALENDAR_CLASS];
[query whereKey:CALENDAR_DATE equalTo:[NSDate date]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Objets are : %@",objects);
        }
    }
}];
```

When I try the same with whereKey:greaterThan then I am getting all the objects matching the query.
Thank you!

Comment: `[NSDate date]` will give you the current date, including the current time, so only records with the current date and exact time will match. This probably isn't what you want

Comment: Yes exactly. Problem is with the time parameters. I found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973914/pfquery-by-date)